# fat-free-framework multi-language: translating a string that includes link?

Tags: fat-free-framework

In fat-free-framework is there any way to translate a string that includes a hyperlink, without using multiple translate file variables?
I've read the [multi-language support documentation](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.7/views-and-templates#MultilingualSupport) and F3 frameworks allow some extra functionality for locales strings but it doesn't seem it is possible?

Let's say I want to translate a sentence that includes hyperlink:

> Help me [get](http://#) translated.

I know I could translate this string like this:

```
$txt_HelpMe => 'Help me',
$txt_Get => 'get',
$txt_Translated = 'translated'
```

And then return the values in my template accordingly:

```
{{$txt_HelpMe}} <a href="#">{{$txt_Get}}</a> {{$txt_Translated}}
```

However, is there any way I could translate this string by using just one variable

```
$txt_HelpMeGetTranslated => '...'
```

and then return it

```
{{@txt_HelpMeGetTranslated }}
```

... while keeping the hyperlink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good question. I assume that your main problem is that Fat-Free Framework is automatically escaping translation messages by default. If you can trust your translated messages, you can un-escape the translation to render hyperlinks (or HTML in general).

1. Translate your messages, e.g. `dict/en.php`

   ```php
   <?php return [
     'translation_invitation_html' => 'Please help us to <a href="https://fatfreeframework.com">translate</a> the software.',
     'translation_invitation_html_placeholder' => 'Please help us to <a href="{0}">translate</a> the software.',
   ]
   ```
2. Format the translated string with or without a placeholder. The result will be escaped (with the default F3 configuration), therefore we have to un-escape the translated messages with the `raw` filter to restore our HTML links.

   ```html
   <ul>
       <li>{{ @translation_invitation_html | raw }}</li>
       <li>{{ @translation_invitation_html_placeholder, 'https://fatfreeframework.com' | format, raw }}</li>
   </ul>
   ```
3. The result will look like this:

   ```html
   <ul>
       <li>Please help us to <a href="https://fatfreeframework.com">translate</a> the software.</li>
       <li>Please help us to <a href="https://fatfreeframework.com">translate</a> the software.</li>
   </ul>
   ```